# Sampling with and without replacement

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling, expected-value

I came across the following question during interview preparation.

"Randomly select 10 **without** replacement from 1000 people, what is the average number of selections it takes to get one person selected?

Randomly select 10 **with** replacement from 1000 people, what is the average number of selections it takes to get one person selected the first time?"

In the case with placement, the probability of each selection that someone being selected P(W) = 1 - (999/1000) ^ 10. How do I generate expected value of number of selections from P(W). Is it 1/P(W)?

In the case without placement, my idea is that there are 100 possible outcomes. The probability of someone being selected in rth outcome is 10/(1000 - 10*r), given previous selections failed to select this guy. I don't know how to translate it into mathematical formula. Please provide better angle to solve this problem.

Reference post [math.stackexchange.com/questions/489772/probability-of-sampling-with-and-without-replacement](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489772/probability-of-sampling-with-and-without-replacement)

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: in sampling without replacement, focus on how many iterations are needed.  That number will be any count from 1 through 100, each equally likely. The answer is immediate.  In sampling with replacement, use a geometric distribution.

Comment: Thanks. So sampling without replacement, it will be 1/100(1+2+...+100) = 50.5. Sampling with replacement, average number of selections is 1/p, where p is 10/1000. So the answer will be 100 times. Are they correct?